# Change the (background?) color behind a flipping view?

Tags: iphone

I have 2 views which transition into each other using the ...

> [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES]

My views both have a black background and when they flip over the colour underneath is white. I want to change this to something else. How do I do this? I have tried searching but I am not really sure which search terms to use.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is changing the background color of your application window (which is visible between the flipside views). You can do this

- either in the Interface Builder in the MainWindow.xib, Tab 1 of the Inspector
- or in code with

  window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 0):

thanks!  Very anti-intuitive. I'd think the superview's background color would show but I'd be wrong ;)